# ! [remote rejected] master -> main (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/immense-anchorage-56196.git

Tags: django, heroku

i am trying to push my code to heroku but i am getting error when i am running push command

**command i am runnin g-->**   `git push heroku master:main`

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
    remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
    remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
    remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
    remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote:  !
    remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 1b461938974e19dafd44baf4db9e9a43f4db7f2e
    remote:  !
    remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 1b461938974e19dafd44baf4db9e9a43f4db7f2e
    remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
    remote:  !
    remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
    remote:  !
    remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
    remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
    remote:
    remote: Verifying deploy...
```

Comment: Have you tried this one `git push heroku master` and from which directory you are trying to push?

Comment: yes i did still not working